# Python Tkinter Label not updating in new window

Tags: python, text, tkinter, updating

So I've got a function that opens a new window. In this window I am trying to update a Label, when I use textvariable it doesn't update and the label always stays blank. With just text, the label will show the text.
My textvariable's work in my main window but not in this one and I have no idea why.

```
def Manage():
    PropsP1 = Tk()
    area = Canvas(PropsP1, width = 920, height = 970)
    area.pack()
    MedCR = StringVar()
    MedO = 1
    count = 1
    MedR = 4
    if MedO == count:
        MedCRLabel = Label(PropsP1, textvariable=MedCR, bg = "White")
        MedCRLabel.place(x = 15, y = 65)
        MedCR.set("Current Rent: "+str(MedR))
```

This is the function, I've tried making multiple Labels and none display anything with textvariable. I can see a white square for the label so I know it is showing up but there is no text.

Comment: What if you make your new window a `TopLevel` instance instead of a `Tk`? Does the problem still occur?

Comment: Yes that fixed it Kevin, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are creating a new instance of `Tk`. A tkinter application should only ever create a single instance of `Tk`, and call `mainloop` exactly once. To create a popup window, create an instance of `Toplevel`.